# Charging 3 cell LiPo with TP4056 (Protection included)

Tags: battery-charging, parallel, series, lithium-polymer

I am trying to charge my three LiPo cells with these [TP4056](https://www.amazon.de/DAOKAI-Lithium-Batterie-Ladebordlader-Module-Schutz/dp/B00XSYIR6Y/ref=pd_sim_23_12?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=1458XXA92XERNMS9FBJ2) modules.

My Idea:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw0PYp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What is your question? By the way, it will not work since the the TP4056 does not have any isolation.

Comment: my question is how can I charge my three LiPo cells with these modules and get my 11.1 volts in the end.

Comment: No. There is a short between IN- and B- for each cell in the TP4056 and you have shorted it on the input. You need to float them/have isolation somewhere.

Comment: I am pretty new to electronics. Can you explain how I can accomplish it to "have isolation somewhere"?

Comment: Can you get three separate 5 V supplies, one for each TP4056?

Comment: ok, so if I supply every TP4056 on its own I can connect them In series and get 11.1 Volts like the schematic shows?

Comment: Yes, provided that each 5 V supply is isolated from each other. Three "wall-wart" 5 V power supplies will do the job. Please draw a schematic of it as an update to your original question.

Comment: And if adding a diode such as 1N4007 between each Out+ and Out- (3x) and before each IN- ?

Comment: Given your lack of familiarity with electronics, and the danger of charging Lipos, I would suggest you get an off the shelf solution.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYKqYU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Thanks for helping @winny

Comment: Given that the 5 V supplies are isolated from each other, that will work. You are welcome!

Comment: This is still a very bad idea.